# HTML word lining

Tags: html, css

This is my line

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
   <h2>ABOUT US</h2></a>
  <a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
    <h2>CONTACT US</h2></a>
  <b> | </b>
  <a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
    <h2>F . A . Q</h2></a>
    <b> | </b>
  <a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
    <h2>SHIPPING</h2></a>
    <b> | </b>
  <a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
    <h2>RETURN POLICY</h2></a>
</p>
```

This is the result:

### ABOUT US

### CONTACT US

**|**

### F . A . Q

**|**

### SHIPPING

**|**

### RETURN POLICY

I want the result to be like this :

```
About Us | Contact Us | F.A.Q | Shipping | Return Policy
```

Anything i did wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's because of the </a> ?

Comment: you need to update your html structure

Comment: @RoySonasish, the div because these are in the table. the table is alligned to the center and the width is auto

Comment: you can't place block elements(h2) inside anchors(a)

Comment: <h2> elements are block elements which are causing the line breaks. remove them and use a different styling structure i.e. font-size: 120%

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal36.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't place block elements(h2) inside anchors(a)

if you remove the `<h2>` from `<a>` then your problem will solve
check the **[updated code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4zgjgu/1/)**

But I thing `ul li` will be the best fit in this structure.

Also if you like to add some space between the `<a>` and `<b>` use `margin`

**[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4zgjgu/2/)**

Comment: Didn't knew <h2> would go to 2nd line

Comment: Is there any ways to change the font?

Comment: use font-family in style

Comment: Or you can use font-size in css

Answer (score 1):

try this:

html:

```
<ul class="hr">
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">ABOUT US</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">CONTACT US</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">F . A . Q</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">SHIPPING</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">RETURN POLICY</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.hr {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 4px; 
}
ul.hr li {
    display: inline; /*displaing your menu in-line*/
    margin-right: 5px; 
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ul class="social_navigation">
    <li><a href="www.facebook.com">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.facebook.com">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.facebook.com">F . A . Q</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com">shipping</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.facebook.com">return policy</a></li>
 </ul>

  ul.social_navigation{
     margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
 ul.social_navigation li{
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   padding:10px;

 }
 ul.social_navigation li a{
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    padding-left:14px;
    font-size:14px;
  }
   ul.social_navigation li:first-child a{
    border-left:none;
    }
   ul.social_navigation li:nth-child(3) a{
     color:#000;
    }
```